# generating spring API docs using swagger over GET endpoints with complex objects

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

I have a spring boot app and I am using springfox swagger to generate the API documentation.

I have a search endpoint with a complex, nested object

```
@GetMapping("/search")
public Something search(SearchDTO input) {
}

public class SearchDTO {
    private SearchFilterDto filters;
    private Page page;
    private Sort sort;
}

public class SearchFilterDto {
    private String name;
}

... other DTOS; getters and setters are omitted, default constructor

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

After running the app, the generated doc looks like this

[image]

Any ideas on to can I help springfox generate documentation for my complex object?

Comment: You cannot pass a DTO to a GET request

Comment: You can. That endpoint works in production as expected :)

Comment: Really? And how do you call the Endpoint?

Comment: `curl --location --request GET '.../search?filters.firstName=x&filters.lastName=y&sort.direction=ASC&sort.field=username&page.offset=1&page.size=2'`. I think this works since spring boot 2.2 if I am not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem.

In my DTOs I had some getters which return `Optional<Something>`. By adding `.genericModelSubstitutes(Optional.class)` to my swagger config I managed to obtain the configuration I was looking for.

```
@Bean
public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build()
            .genericModelSubstitutes(Optional.class)  // added this line
            .securityContexts(Lists.newArrayList(securityContext()))
            .securitySchemes(Lists.newArrayList(apiKey()));
}
```